# Need help identifying several react-component sliders

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a project that I'm needing to incorporate a slider to allow a user to select a range of configurations.  I can use the slider and get it to work, but I need to have several sliders on a single form and the only thing that is returned with the onChange event is the number or the range of numbers for a slider of type range.  Does anyone know how to name these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to handle this.  Before, I was passing in the event doing this:

```
onChange={(event) => {this.handleVolumeChange(event)}}
```

The issue with this is that the event that is fired is a mouse event and it doesn't have the information needed on the event.target.value like I'm used to using for other form inputs, etc.
The solution is to do this:

```
onChange={(value) => {this.handleVolumeChange(value, 'volume-slider')}}
```

By passing a different argument than event, I was able to get the value and also pass in a for the slider.  Now I will be able to have dynamic adding and removing on the form and handle which slider needs it's information updated.  Hope this helps someone else!